How a Batch Script recognize the source that executed it?
How does the batch script known the source that executed it?

Executed / called from Command line CMD
Executed from Batch file (either from the file itself or another batch file)

Illustration:
@Echo off
:: Test.bat
:: From CLI or Batch File
pause


.@Gantendo do you mean %cmdcmdline%. in poweshel $MyInvocation?

To find out whether it was executed from Command Line or from Batch, by check one of LINES or COLUMNS variable.
It's not defined yet from Batch. So, SET | Find /I "LINES="
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET | Findstr /I /C:"LINES=" >NUL
::echo %ERRORLEVEL%& pause& exit /b 
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo Executed from CLI
) else (
    echo Executed from Batch
    pause
)
ENDLOCAL

I tried to execute it both from CLI or its file or from another batch file. giving different results.
